# Using Semantic UI React in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Is there anything different about creating a React App as a Chrome extension? I've used Semantic UI React in the past with regular React Applications, but just can't seem to get it to work when using it within a Chrome extension.

I ran a `yarn add semantic-ui-react` and added this to the `index.html` in my create-react-app:

```
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css"
    />
```

I then tried to render a component within the React App:

```
export const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu inverted>
        <Menu.Item name="TEST" />
      </Menu>
      <Button>TEST</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
export const Test;
```

But when loading this extension in Chrome, I got this, which obviously doesn't look like it has any Semantic UI CSS attached to it.
[image: Semantic UI React Chrome Extension Failure]

Comment: Your `href` lacks the protocol so the popup's protocol is used which is `chrome-extension://` which you can see in devtools: right-click inside the popup, then click 'inspect'.

Comment: Does this mean that my ```href``` should be formatted differently in a Chrome extension?

Comment: It should start with `https://`

Comment: Wow that worked, thanks! Curious to see how the setup instructions have a link that works with regular React Apps but doesn't play nice with Chrome extensions https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage